# Why is my result returning a strange value when I'm trying to recursively compute the sum of integers between two values?

Tags: java, recursion

It returns a value similar to 02212138841293291. I know that integers have the zeros removed and the sum of number between 0 and 11 do not scale that high. Language Java (I apologize is that is not clear)

```
public class Sum1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int end = 11;
        int start = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        sums(start, end, sum);
    }

    public static void sums(int start, int end, int sum) {

        if(start<= end) {   
            sum += start;
        start += 1;
            sums(start, end, sum);
        }
         System.out.print(sum); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "odd value"?  A "strange and unexpected" value, or a value that you expect to be "not even"?

Comment: It's clearly a C-family language, @MooingDuck.  I ran it through C# and got the expected result: 0.  Which, I hasten to point out, is even, not odd.  :-)

Comment: funny how the question now looks like my answer

Comment: @JoeT I had previously done what you answered and it still produced numbers like what Mooning Duck posted 6666554536282115106310. So to show that it didnt matter I reposted my previous code or your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call "sums" from within sums, you're resetting "sum" back to 0.  You would need to pass the sum into sums each time.

```
public class Sum1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int end = 11;
    int start = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    sums(start, end, sum);
  }

  public static void sums(int start, int end, int sum) {  
    if(start<= end) {   
        sum += start;
        start += 1;
        sums(start, end, sum);
    }
     System.out.print(sum); 
  }

}
```

Comment: it still returns some number like this 01112330243143191

Comment: Your function "sums" has two parms, but you're calling it in "main" by passing three parms. This couldn't possibly build.

Comment: Until he said it was Java I tried to figure out how on earth he expected to compute from a recursion which never returned a value.  As it happens, Java does not use "out" parameters, so now I am happier.  Does C use "out" parms?  Can't find my K&R.